# ORA-06550 error PLS-00103 error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    DECLARE 

    nAnid                   NUMBER;
    vPin                    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
    vUse_type           VARCHAR2(20 BYTE);
    vApp_num              VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
    dApp_date              DATE;
    vDisplay                  VARCHAR2(3 BYTE);
    vApp_status            VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
    mShape                  mdsys.sdo_geometry;

  /* get records that exist in dgi but not in kiv using anid */
   CURSOR curGetMJ IS
    SELECT d.anid,d. pin, d.use_type, d.app_num, d.app_date, d.display, d.app_status, d.shape
    FROM   dsdspa.dsd_marijuana@dgi d
    WHERE d.anid not in
      (select anid from kivaprod.marijuana);

  curGetMJ_rec curGetMJ%ROWTYPE;     

BEGIN

    OPEN  curGetMJ;
      LOOP
         FETCH  curGetMJ INTO  curGetMJ_rec;
           EXIT WHEN  curGetMJ%NOTFOUND;
           vAnid                                    :=  curGetMJ_rec.anid;
           vPin                               :=  curGetMJ_rec.pin;
           vUse_type                            :=  curGetMJ_rec.use_type;
           vApp_num                            :=  curGetMJ_rec.app_num;
           dApp_date                      :=  curGetMJ_rec.app_num;
           vDisplay                             :=  curGetMJ_rec.display;
           vApp_status                        :=  curGetMJ_rec.app_status;
           mShape                               :=  curGetMJ_rec.shape;

           INSERT INTO KIVAPROD.MARIJUANA
            (anid, pin, use_type, app_num, app_date, display, app_status, shape)
           VALUES
            (307, '14211', 'D', '15-05', 2015-04-15, 'Y', '', mShape);

     END LOOP;
   CLOSE  curGetMJ;
```

Comment: I receive this error: ORA-06550: line 42, column 19:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge

Comment: I am extremely new to this and this was provided to me to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend to please edit the question and provide the additional information there instead of in the comments section.

Comment: do you have END for the begin clause after CLOSE  curGetMJ;?

Comment: No, I do not. Is that needed? I can try that. I apologize if there is confusion. I am lost to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Missing `END;` for the entire `BEGIN...END;` block.